# Call report from C# class file

Tags: c#, .net, oop, crystal-reports

How can I call an existing Crystal Report from my C# class file?

My method in the class file has the parameter string `CallCrystal(string num)`. The report in is located in `D:/Reports/EmployeDetails/` which displays the employee detail by passing in string input.

The method should send this string as a parameter (num) and call the report to crystal report.

Answer (score 0):

You need the CrystalReportViewer Control. This has a ReportSource property which, inter alia, can be set to the path of an existing report, which is your case. In order to add parameters, you will in addition need to use the ParameterFieldInfo member which is a collection of ParameterFields. Set this as follows:

```
ParameterFields paramFlds = new ParameterFields();
ParameterField param = new ParameterField();
ParameterDiscreteValue paramVal = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
param.Name = "myName";
paramVal.Value = myValue;
param.CurrentValues.Add(paramVal);
paramFlds.Add(param);
```

I use a single "host" form containing just one control, the CrystalReportViewer.  To view the report, I create an instance of this form, passing in whatever parameters I need (at least the ParameterFieldInfo, but in your case including path as well) and finally call host.Show() to view the report.